# is N logv2(N) the same as N log N?

Tags: logarithms

In one place I'm reading the performance of a heapsort is

```
N log₂(N)
```

and in another it says

```
N log N
```

Are they the same?

Comment: Usually in computer science $\log$ denotes the logarithm in base 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\log_2(N) = \frac{ \log{N}}{\log{2}}$ for all $N$, and $\log{2}$ is only a constant, they are the same in the sense that $N \log_2{N} = O(N \log{N})$, and vice versa.

Comment: Be aware that the other side of this is not true: $O(2^N)$, $O(e^N)$ and  $O(10^N)$ do not mean the same things as each other